# How does double-click (with no hyperlink) work on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, html

You probably have noticed this behavior on [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/webpage)  : on double-clicking a word, the page reloads showing the meaning of the double-clicked word.

For example, the meaning of the word ['webpage'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/webpage) on thefreedictionary is,

> web·page or Web page
>
> A **document** on the World Wide Web,
> consisting of an HTML file and
>          any related files for scripts and
> graphics, and often hyperlinked to
>          other documents on the Web.

So if you double-click on a word, say *document*, then the page reloads and the reloaded page shows the meaning of *document*.

The interesting thing which attracted my attention is that the words on which I double-click are not even hyperlink. They look as normal as these words you're reading right now.

So my question is : How does it work? How does double-click (with no hyperlink) work on a webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, it's as simple as doing this.

```
<span id="test">testig testing</span>

$('#test').dblclick(function(){
alert('whatever')
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/vkpgY/

Comment: Thanks for working example, and the link. It's new to me; I can experiment more example there. :-)

Comment: Great. You can also try to replace dblclick with click or hover if you want to have such behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an ondblclick handler to any item on the page, including single words, groups of words, etc:

```
hello <span ondblclick="alert('hi');">bob</b>
```

In the dictionary's case, you could get the value of the double-clicked item and then construct a URL around it. Suppose you had jQuery. You could do something like this (not tested):

```
hello <span ondblclick="window.location = 'http://dictionary.com/words/' + $(this).text();">bob</b>
```

Comment: Did you see the source code of thefreedictionary page? They didn't implement it like that. See yourself : http://www.thefreedictionary.com/webpage  ... they didn't sandwich each word with such html tag!

Comment: They have a `ondblclick="dictionary()"` handler on the `<body>` tag. Same idea; they're just more clever about determining what's a word. You can see the source: http://img.tfd.com/dict2.js

Answer (score 1):

There is a Javascript `dblclick` event handler that gets called whenever you double click. You can use it as follows, on an arbitrary element:

`element.addEventHandler('dblclick', function() { alert('Double clicked.'); });`

Be sure not to have both a `dblclick` and `click` event handler on the same element, because the `click` will fire twice in this case.

See also: [element.ondlbclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.ondblclick)

Answer (score -1):

```
<span onclick="sample()"> hi </span>
<div id="show"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sample()
{
    var ajax = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest:new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    ajax.open("GET","process.php?q=apple",true);
    ajax.send();
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200){
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
        }}
}
</script>


in process.php file
<? var_dump($_REQUEST)?>//you do whatever u want like this..!
```

is it enough for you Nawaz bother..?

Comment: Why did you not edit your old post? Would you keep on adding new post each time?

Comment: k.. i will do it from now onwards.. thanks for your advice.. did u get what you asked me.?